# how to call stored procedure using ef core and clean architecture

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, clean-architecture

Using asp.net ef core, clean architecture, repository/service & uow pattern

Considering that insert should not be done in repository class and
On the other hand in the service layer we can not call dbContext directly
Suppose we want to use stored procedures or raw queries in some part of the project,

For example, we want to do what is said in the link below

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-set-explicit-value-to-id-property-in-ef-core.aspx

Or call a Stored Precedure that does the insert by Database.ExcecuteSqlCommand

**How can we do this without disturbing the architecture?**
Where we should call the SP?

My project architecture is so alike this tutorial

[Repository Pattern Done Right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM)

---

Edit:
for more clarification:
this is add method of user repository class:

```
 public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly tablighkadeDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserRepository(tablighkadeDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Add(User user)
    {
            Entities.User newUser = new Entities.User
            {
                
                Email = user.Email,
                ...
            };
           await _dbContext.AddAsync(newUser);          
    }
```

CompeleteAsync method in unitOfWork class:

```
 public async  Task<int> CompeleteAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

and finally I have service class in core layer, I persist entity like this:

```
 public async Task RegisterUser(UserAddVM userAddVM)
    {           
        
        var user = await _unitOfWork.Users.GetByEmail(userAddVM.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
         //...
        }             
        else {
            var u = new User
            {
                Email = userAddVM.Email,
                //...               
            };
           await _unitOfWork.Users.Add(u);
           await _unitOfWork.CompeleteAsync();              
        }
        
    }
```

But I don't know what to do the same using stored procedure,

considering we should not save/update entities in repository class based on this article and some other articles I read

https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/

Comment: What do you mean with "Considering that insert should not be done in repository "? It is a repository issue to persist entities, where do you want to place it?

Comment: please read the part Save/Update method in repositories of this article, https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/

Comment: normally I persist the entity in service class using uow, like this: await _unitOfWork.Users.Add(u);
               await _unitOfWork.SaveChangeAsync(); but using stored procedure I dont know what to do

Comment: @RenéLink I Edited my question and added some code for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can extend generic EFRepository class to have your own implementation. You should expose this implementation via Interface.

Here is an example of OrderRepository: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Data/OrderRepository.cs

In this example they have implemented GetByIdWithItemsAsync(int id), similarly you can have your own implementation.

You can add a method in UserRepository. If your insert logic is in Stored Proc then you don't require to commit using `_dbContext.SaveChanges()`. Commit will happen in Stored Proc which will not be in your control. To refresh the state, you can have select for inserted entity at the end of stored proc and which should update the persistent entity .

```
public async Task Add(User user)
{
    var user = _dbContext.Users.SqlQuery("dbo.AddUser @p0 ", user.Name).Single();
}
```

Comment: I have my own repository classes already! and have no problem with select queries, I can write them by linq or sp in repository class. but as I said I want to know where call Insert stored procedure? cause based on my research insert should not be done in repository class.                                   https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gone through the video but I said with respect to Clean Architecture. You can even write a method in repo class to call stored procedure and call that from your service class. If you have any custom object then you can create a DTO and do the CRUD operation in Service class calling the repo class.

Comment: @AmaryllisLavender based on your code I have updated my response. For inserting through Stored Proc you don't need to call method CompeleteAsync().

Comment: thanks a lot @Ashish Jain, I found 
I have to write a service in the data layer (Infrastructure layer) to work directly with the database (for example, Deper, or ado or call sp) 
and to use it in the handler, put the interface of this service in the application layer. 
This service does not have repository properties (ie not in memory) but work directly with database without disturbing the architecture.